# Magento - Orders with wit CC not changing to Complete after Send Order

Tags: php, html, magento

I have an Issue on the Magento 1.9 backend. I have a several payment methods, and the one with Mastercard or Visa is not working well.

After i got an Order it shows me that the amount has been authorized and it creates automatically an invoice for this order. Than i click on "Send Order" and it should be switch from status: "pending" to "complete" but it's not doing it. I had some other orders yesterday but not with the Creditcard, this worked well.

What could be the reason for such issue?